# PyQt6 pyinstaller app builds but wont open MacOS (M1 chip)

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller, pyqt6

I am trying to make a python desktop app with PyQt6. I want to make it into a clickable app by using pyinstaller but I get a "app closed unexpectedly" error when I try to run the app from finder. Equally I cant run the app from terminal either but the app works fine when run through my IDE without pyinstaller.

To test it isnt my app, I have made a fresh environment with different python versions and used the following simple app code from the PyQt website (https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/pyqt6-creating-your-first-window/)

Python version 3.9
pyinstaller version 5.13.0
pyqt6 version 6.5.2

When trying to launch the app and it crashes, sending the logs to apple gives a segmentation fault as follows:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000008
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000008

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process:   exc handler [26876]

VM Region Info: 0x8 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 105553518919672
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      MALLOC_NANO (reserved)   600018000000-600020000000 [128.0M] rw-/rwx SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   CoreFoundation                         0x1922c665c _CFGetNonObjCTypeID + 92
1   CoreFoundation                         0x1921982ec CFBundleCopyBundleURL + 24
2   QtCore                                 0x102380a5c QLibraryInfoPrivate::path(QLibraryInfo::LibraryPath, QLibraryInfoPrivate::UsageMode) + 440
3   QtCore                                 0x1023810ac QLibraryInfoPrivate::path(QLibraryInfo::LibraryPath, QLibraryInfoPrivate::UsageMode) + 2056
4   QtCore                                 0x1023b7470 0x102374000 + 275568
5   QtCore                                 0x1023b6a6c 0x102374000 + 273004
6   QtCore                                 0x1023b8fd4 0x102374000 + 282580
7   QtCore                                 0x1023b5c58 QLoggingCategory::QLoggingCategory(char const*, QtMsgType) + 52
8   QtCore.abi3.so                         0x10509cde0 warmUpLocationServices() + 268
9   QtCore.abi3.so                         0x10509f724 _GLOBAL__sub_I_qdarwinpermissionplugin_location.mm + 12
10  dyld                                   0x191dd81d8 invocation function for block in dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const::$_0::operator()() const + 168
11  dyld                                   0x191e19c60 invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void (unsigned int) block_pointer, void const*) const + 172
12  dyld                                   0x191e0d1a4 invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void (dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&) block_pointer) const + 528
13  dyld                                   0x191db82d8 dyld3::MachOFile::forEachLoadCommand(Diagnostics&, void (load_command const*, bool&) block_pointer) const + 296
14  dyld                                   0x191e0c1cc dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void (dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&) block_pointer) const + 192
15  dyld                                   0x191e0ecfc dyld3::MachOFile::forEachInitializerPointerSection(Diagnostics&, void (unsigned int, unsigned int, bool&) block_pointer) const + 160
16  dyld                                   0x191e19904 dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void (unsigned int) block_pointer, void const*) const + 432
17  dyld                                   0x191dd485c dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const + 448
18  dyld                                   0x191dd4c10 dyld4::Loader::runInitializersBottomUp(dyld4::RuntimeState&, dyld3::Array<dyld4::Loader const*>&) const + 220
19  dyld                                   0x191dd8264 dyld4::Loader::runInitializersBottomUpPlusUpwardLinks(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const::$_1::operator()() const + 112
20  dyld                                   0x191dd4d90 dyld4::Loader::runInitializersBottomUpPlusUpwardLinks(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const + 304
21  dyld                                   0x191df2d58 dyld4::APIs::dlopen_from(char const*, int, void*) + 1440
22  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100dfa844 _PyImport_FindSharedFuncptr + 296
23  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100db599c _imp_create_dynamic + 1108
24  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100ced0fc cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 200
25  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d847dc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27276
26  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d7d444 _PyEval_Vector + 2056
27  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d886d4 call_function + 524
28  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d84464 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 26388
29  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d7d444 _PyEval_Vector + 2056
30  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d886d4 call_function + 524
31  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d8443c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 26348
32  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d7d444 _PyEval_Vector + 2056
33  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d886d4 call_function + 524
34  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d844d4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 26500
35  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d7d444 _PyEval_Vector + 2056
36  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d886d4 call_function + 524
37  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d844d4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 26500
38  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d7d444 _PyEval_Vector + 2056
39  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d886d4 call_function + 524
40  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d844d4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 26500
41  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d7d444 _PyEval_Vector + 2056
42  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100c9b894 object_vacall + 272
43  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100c9bab4 _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 128
44  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100db1a28 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 1284
45  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d770b4 builtin___import__ + 124
46  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100cec3a0 cfunction_call + 80
47  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100c9998c _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 612
48  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100c9ac48 _PyObject_CallFunctionVa + 776
49  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100c9a918 PyObject_CallFunction + 64
50  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100db13e8 PyImport_Import + 552
51  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100db27e0 PyImport_ImportModule + 60
52  sip.cpython-310-darwin.so              0x100be1754 sip_api_export_module + 88
53  QtWidgets.abi3.so                      0x1017c1188 PyInit_QtWidgets + 276
54  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100db59ec _imp_create_dynamic + 1188
55  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100ced0fc cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 200
56  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d847dc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27276
57  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d7d444 _PyEval_Vector + 2056
58  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d886d4 call_function + 524
59  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d84464 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 26388
60  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d7d444 _PyEval_Vector + 2056
61  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d886d4 call_function + 524
62  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d8443c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 26348
63  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d7d444 _PyEval_Vector + 2056
64  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d886d4 call_function + 524
65  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d844d4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 26500
66  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d7d444 _PyEval_Vector + 2056
67  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d886d4 call_function + 524
68  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d844d4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 26500
69  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d7d444 _PyEval_Vector + 2056
70  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d886d4 call_function + 524
71  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d844d4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 26500
72  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d7d444 _PyEval_Vector + 2056
73  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100c9b894 object_vacall + 272
74  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100c9bab4 _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 128
75  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100db1a28 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 1284
76  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d770b4 builtin___import__ + 124
77  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100cec3a0 cfunction_call + 80
78  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100c9a3a0 _PyObject_Call + 148
79  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d847dc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27276
80  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d7d444 _PyEval_Vector + 2056
81  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d886d4 call_function + 524
82  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d844d4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 26500
83  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d7d444 _PyEval_Vector + 2056
84  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100c9b894 object_vacall + 272
85  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100c9bab4 _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 128
86  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100db1ba0 PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 1660
87  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d82b40 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 19952
88  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d7d444 _PyEval_Vector + 2056
89  libpython3.10.dylib                    0x100d7cc0c PyEval_EvalCode + 120
90  main                                   0x10074c8ec 0x100748000 + 18668
91  main                                   0x10074cf10 0x100748000 + 20240
92  dyld                                   0x191dbbf28 start + 2236
```

I have tried other frameworks such as py2app, changing pyqt versions, changing python versions, running on a ubuntu machine (new OS) on aws and tried on a different mac device and still no luck. I have also tried all the different flags from pyinstaller e.g `--onefile` and `--onedir`. I have also seen and tried the stack overflow suggestion to use the dev version of pyinstaller but this did not resolve the issue. Any help would be massively appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show the actual code you used. Note that it's unclear if when you say "I cant run from terminal either" you mean that you're trying to run the python code or the pyinstaller binary. If it's the latter, please show us the command you used to build the executable, if it's the former, then this has absolutely nothing to do with pyinstaller. Still, we need a valid [mre] to work with.

Answer (score 2):

After much searching, the key term that led me to the answer ended up being the `Segmentation fault: 11`. Once this was found then the fix that worked for me came from the following post (https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/7789) which was:

```
pip uninstall pyinstaller
PYINSTALLER_COMPILE_BOOTLOADER=1 pip install git+https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller.git@develop
```

I hope this helps if anyone else runs into the same issue!